# Android GoogleCardboard VR gaze tracking

Tags: android, google-cardboard

My project is to create a player who support google cardboard vr. The problem is that I want to pause / play the video when the phone is situated in VR glasses.

After doing some research I found out that "gaze tracking" or "gaze input" will do the trick.

I saw many examples with gaze tracking in Unity but i don't know how can be embed with my android aplication. Pause / Play button should be an overlay over video renderer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GVR Gaze on camera and IGVRResponder interface to get its methods like GVRGazeEnter();